# Criar um repositório do Github / git

Tags: git, github

Estou tentando criar um repositório do *github*, mas alguma coisa está dando errado e eu não consigo identificar o que:

Estou usando:

- windows 10 //
- git version 2.22.0.windows//
- node v10.16.0 //
- Browser
- sync v2.26.7 //
- sublime text 3 //

Os passos que estou seguindo - no github:

```
create a new repository ---
name it ---
settings> github pages> master blanch ----
back to the main and copy the link
```

No terminal:

```
git clone <LINK> ----
cd <NAME OF THE REPOSITORY> ----
dir
```

No sublime:

Depois que eu crio o arquivo *index.html* e salvo na pasta, eu dou o comando 'git status' e o terminal não mostra o arquivo index criado, aparece a msg:

> ```
> "On branch master Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.
>  nothing to commit, working tree clean"
> ```

eu já verifiquei algumas vezes e não estou entendendo o que está dando errado..

Comment: Se o arquivo é novo, precisa adicionar com `git add index.html`. E depois fazer o commit do arquivo, push, etc...

Comment: Ou tu pode adicionar tudo de uma vez com o `git add .`

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente sua `branch` não possui nada, assim você deveria adiciona alguma coisa no seu `stage`. Assim com os comandos abaixo voce pode adicionar items em seu Github.

com o comando:

```
git add .
```

ou pode especificar com o nome do arquivo com comando:

```
git add arquivo.js
```

posteriormente

```
git commit -m "initial commit"
```

pode confirmar seu stage

```
 git status
```

e por fim empurra-los para a `origin master`com

```
 git push origin master ou 

 ou 

 git push
```

Comment: ah sim! 
Eu ainda fiquei um pouco confusa com algumas coisas, mas aparentemente deu tudo certo por hora.
Muito obrigada!

Comment: boa, se possível evite deixar questões em aberto marcar